# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'misaka'

Tags: python-3.x, django-templates

In python misaka module not able to install while installing pip install misaka showing download error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Vi
sual C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/
please suggest the above solution. i checked python version for system 64 same is there.

Answer (score 0):

use following code in your cmd
pip install misaka
to install miska library

some example
from misaka import Markdown, HtmlRenderer

```py
rndr = HtmlRenderer()
md = Markdown(rndr)

print(md('some text'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Working solution!

Go to https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/ scroll down one page and download Visual Studio 2017 community.

Go through following link to download the required components for Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0, the link provides what components to be selected while downloading.

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/409173/error-microsoft-visual-c-140-is-required.html

Once the download finishes, you will be asked to restart your system.

Having restarted your system, type

pip install django-misaka

Hope it works as it worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

you should have install the module using pip

pip install django-misaka

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).